# group node to link and animate multiple alphas

Tags: node-editor

Noob to Blender and to nodes.

To animate the transparency of an object with a dozen (very simple) materials, I would like to link all the alphas with a single keyframable value. I think this is possible using an instanced node group (just a 0-1 value node or an alpha node) to input into the alpha of each of the materials, but would be most grateful for help with how to set this up.

Many thanks!

Comment: Just create a single *Input > Value* node and group it alone. Use this node group on your multiple materials.